# How to get the URL for a route in hug?

Tags: python-3.x, hug

In flask, one can easily get the URL for a given endpoint using [url_for()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for). Is there an equivalent in Hug?

I'd like to automatically generate the URLs for various resources in my REST API for inclusion in the responses.